# How to use dhooks to find the most recent message sent in a channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, webhooks

I want to know how to get the most recent message sent in a channel of a discord server with discord webhooks in python? I have not tried anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

Webhooks are only meant for sending messages, not reading messages in a channel. The only way to get the last message from the channel is if you have a bot user in the server that can read message history in that channel.